# Item level permissions settings for a document library in sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, permissions, list-item

How can I get item level permissions settings for a document library in SharePoint 2013. Something like below

[image: item level permissions]

I want to create a page where everybody will be able to create/add their post/picture. However I want to show all documents to every user, but the user can edit the properties of their own documents only

Answer (score 1):

This can be done through Power Shell. Below is a sample snippet

```
$site = Get-SPSite http://<<Site URL>>
$web = $site.RootWeb
$list= $web.Lists["Documents"]
$list.WriteSecurity = 2
$list.Update()
```

Refer these links for more information about WriteSecurity Property - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splist.writesecurity.aspx

Similarly you can set the ReadSecurity property as well. Hope this helps.

Regards
Ram.

Comment: Can you use this for document libraries?

EDIT: According to this, you can:

http://www.hersheytech.com/Blog/SharePoint/tabid/197/entryid/28/Default.aspx

Comment: Yes this can be used for all Document Libraries.

Comment: @Ram Thanks Ram for your answer. I have tried the above and it didn’t work. Is there any other way of doing this? 

Regards
Anwar

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved by creating a workflow by following the below web link.

http://www.sharepointusecases.com/2010/03/configure-item-level-permissions-for-document-libraries-part-2/

Comment: Can you please add details from the link, Links has a potential problem to break.

Comment: @AsadRefai we don't have any OOB option setup item level permissions for the documents. Even we can't do it with the powershell. We have only option to do with workflow. Using workflow we can replace the permissions once it is created.